# Changing boot order while using ipxe with nova

Tags: pxe-boot, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-glance

I am using ipxe to boot a VM with openstack Nova.

Here is the answer link i have used to setup my boot process

[Does nova support pxe boot?](https://serverfault.com/questions/469479/does-nova-support-pxe-boot)

I am using the answer by larsks to boot the VM using ipxe. It works well but when i try to reboot a VM it does a PXE again. What I want is that the second time i boot, the VM should boot normally. Or even better that somehow i should be able to tell whether i want to do a pxe boot this time or a normal boot.

Thanks in Advance.